# Merge 2 jQuery functions

Tags: jquery, function, merge

I have 2 jQuery functions that basicly are written the same except for their 1st lines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var h = $(window).height();
 var w = $(window).width();
 $('#foo').css({'height' : h});
 $('#foo').css({'width' : w});
});

$(window).resize(function() {
 var h = $(window).height();
 var w = $(window).width();
 $('#foo').css({'height' : h});
 $('#foo').css({'width' : w});
});
```

so I was wondering if its possible to merge them into 1 some how?

As always thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trigger the `resize` event manually:

```
$(function() { // shortcut for $(document).ready(function() {...});
    $(window).resize(function() {   // bind the handler
        $('#foo').css({
            'height': $(window).height(),
            'width': $(window).width()
        });
    }).resize(); // trigger the resize event
});
```

or create an extra function and bind it to both events:

```
function resizeHandler() {
    $('#foo').css({
        'height': $(window).height(),
        'width': $(window).width()
    });
}

$(document).ready(resizeHandler);
$(window).resize(resizeHandler);
```

---

Btw. `$(function(){...});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`.

Comment: Why not combine the `.css()`? Just sayin' haha

Comment: @Felix Kling I have to razz you out of animosity because you beat me on time!

Comment: Thank you, this seems the better option due to what Emil said about load in next post, and why I didn't merge the css() in the first place I don't know lol

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFunction = function() {
 var h = $(window).height();
 var w = $(window).width();
 $('#foo').css({'height' : h});
 $('#foo').css({'width' : w});
}

$(document).ready(myFunction);
$(window).resize(myFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function yourfunc() {
 var h = $(window).height();
 var w = $(window).width();
 $('#foo').css({'height' : h});
 $('#foo').css({'width' : w});
}

$(document).ready(yourfunc);
$(window).resize(yourfunc);
```

Another way to call it (longer but more understandable) would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   yourfunc();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
   yourfunc();
});
```

Both work. Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

create a third function

```
function calculateSomething(){
  var h = $(window).height();
  var w = $(window).width();
  $('#foo').css({'height' : h, 'width' : w}});
}
```

Then call the function

```
$(document).ready(calculateSomething);

$(window).resize(calculateSomething);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use do:

```
$(window).bind('load resize', function(e){
    $('#foo').css({'width' : $(window).width(), 'height': $(window).height()});
});
```

Comment: load will wait for all the external files and images to be loaded before calling the function.